Is there a technical name for VPNs like ZeroTier (Tinc, n2n, ...)?
While I enjoy the remote access and virtual LAN chat rooms powered by ZeroTier, I am curious about why ZeroTier is referred to by so many names (SDWAN, VLAN, ZeroTrust, Ad-hoc VPN, Secure LAN, Virtual Ethernet Switch, etc.) on the Internet, and whether there is a technical definition of what it does.
My question is: Is there a formal technical name for the functionalities of ZeroTier (like “Site-to-site VPN”), or is it a too narrow use case to be named? To be specific, the points are:

Connect neither two sites (Site-to-Site) nor a physical remote site (Remote-Access). All peers join a virtual LAN, different from their own hosted LAN;
Peers can join and leave dynamically, with zero config;
Peers can discover each other (i.e., supports network broadcasting).


I have read this post which offered me some insights, such as Mesh VPN (seems to be more emphasis on decentralization trait in the implementation), DMVPN (seems like a marketing term from Cisco), Zero Trust Overlay Network and SD-WAN. But I am not sure which describe these functionalities best.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Have you googled each of these terms, all except ZeroTrust are features, ZeroTrust is a marketing trrm

@Ramhound Yes I certainly googled them before asking. Do you mean there is no standard name for the points I listed?

Clarification to Moderators: (1) I've highlighted my problem in the question. It is neither vague nor broad. Is it considered vague simply because I listed a few points?  (2) I am not the only one coming here to ask a technical name for some features or products: Question 1, Question 2, Question 3 and more.

@w568w "Do you mean there is no standard name for the points I listed?" - You listed the standard names for those features.  SD-WAN is a software-defined WAN, for instance.

@Ramhound I know! My point is whether there is one official technical name that describes all the features I mentioned. Or do I have to say “It's a dynamic SD-WAN & Meshed & Zero-Config & Zero-Trust & Discoverable VPN” when I introduce ZeroTier to someone?

One issue I have with this question is that all those features are not unique to ZeroTier. It just has e.g. a nicer web UI for adding peers as opposed to OpenVPN where peers can also come and go as they want and they also pull 95% of config from the control server (not zero-config but that's just because ZeroTier has the other 5% hardcoded) and it can also connect whole sites and so on and so on.
